# How to pass a large array to a Rails path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We need to pass a large array of ids (may be a few thousands of them) to a path in rails:

```
rails_path(ids: large_id_array)
```

There is error of `Request-URI Too Large` popping up in development passing an array of 2700 ids. What's the size limit when passing an array to a rails path? Is there any way getting around the size limitation?

Comment: There is not a limit by Ruby, or Rails, the limit is usually the server you are running the processes on... Bigger servers can handle more requests... Why do you need to pass so many into an array? Could we see an example of what the problem is?

Comment: abbott567, we are trying to find a way to export the current page to csv file with a custom action. That's why we need to pass all the ids to the custom action and sometimes ids may be many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass as many args in the path as you want with POST params (you were trying to pass GET params):

- **GET params are visible** in the URL (example: `/users?is_admin=true` the `params[:is_admin]` is equal to `"true"` in this case)
- **POST params are not visible** in the URL (like when you click on "login" button after you've filled the username/password fields, for obvious security reasons you don't want to print the fields in the URL)

---

In your case, you should pass the ids as POST params. How to send POST params in a request? Just ask `link_to` to use `POST` method instead of `GET`:

```
link_to 'Click here!', rails_path(ids: large_array_of_ids), method: :post
```

---

Another way to create a POST link:

```
# HAML code
= form_tag rails_path(ids: large_array_of_ids) do
  = submit_tag 'Click here!'

# ERB code
<%= form_tag rails_path(ids: large_array_of_ids) do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Click here!' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: MrYooshiji, the error is the same after adding method: :post. Is it the limitation by webrick web server (rails development)?

Comment: No it's not really the issue here. You are trying to access to a URL that is exceeding the allowed length. I'll update my answer in a sec with the `form_tag` method

Comment: link_to is exactly what we are using to embed a CSV link on a form.

Comment: I know but `link_to` can't really create a POST request. POST params are set with a regular form. See my update with the `form_tag` and ask me if you need clarification(s)

Comment: **<%= form_tag export_file_onboard_user_accesses_path(format: 'csv', query: models.first.try(:class).try(:pluck,'id')), method: :post do %>
       <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
<% end %>**           . Here is what we tried and still the same error (URI too large). Tried without method: :post and the error is the same.

Comment: oh! The content of the CSV does not depend on the user's input, then you can simply hold the logic that retrieves the wanted IDs inside the controller's action ;-)

Comment: The content of CSV depends on user's input and needs to be passed to action controller in the id array.

Comment: submit_tag can piggy peg variable which could be very large in size and pass the variable into the controller.